# Recyclerview : Load more in Blogger API doesn't smooth

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have successfully to get next page of post using Blogger's API, but i can't achieve the smooth scrolling of recyclerview, it look lagging.

I have tried using `recyclerViewData.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but still doesn't work.

My point is How to achieve smooth of recyclerview. Any suggestion will be appreciate. thank is advance.

Here is my code

```
private void getData() {
            showLoading(true);
            final Call<ResponseBlogPost> postList = apiService.getListPost(GlobalVariable.APP_KEY);
            postList.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBlogPost>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBlogPost> call, Response<ResponseBlogPost> response) {
                    showLoading(false);
                    ResponseBlogPost responseBlogPost = response.body();
                    initDataView(responseBlogPost);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBlogPost> call, Throwable t) {
                    showLoading(false);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

private void initDataView(ResponseBlogPost listpost){
            GlobalFunction.saveString(this,GlobalVariable.TOKEN_PAGINATION, listpost.getNextPageToken());
            final String nextPageToken = GlobalFunction.getStrings(this, GlobalVariable.TOKEN_PAGINATION);
            itemsList.addAll(listpost.getItems());
            adapter = new MainAdapter(itemsList) {
                @Override
                public void load() {
                    if(nextPageToken==null){
                        return;
                    }
                    getNextListPost();
                }
            };

            recyclerViewData.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerViewData.setHasFixedSize(true);
            staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,1);
            staggeredGridLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(0);
            recyclerViewData.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
        }


private void getNextListPost(){
            showLoading(true);
            final String nextPageToken = GlobalFunction.getStrings(this, GlobalVariable.TOKEN_PAGINATION);
            Call<ResponseBlogPost>  call = apiService.getNexPageListPost(GlobalVariable.APP_KEY,nextPageToken);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBlogPost>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBlogPost> call, Response<ResponseBlogPost> response) {
                    showLoading(false);
                    ResponseBlogPost responseModel = response.body();
                    if(nextPageToken!=null){
                        initDataView2(responseModel);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tidak ada data lagi ya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBlogPost> call, Throwable t) {
                    showLoading(false);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }


private void initDataView2(ResponseBlogPost listpost){
            GlobalFunction.saveString(this,GlobalVariable.TOKEN_PAGINATION, listpost.getNextPageToken());
            final String nextPageToken = GlobalFunction.getStrings(this, GlobalVariable.TOKEN_PAGINATION);
            itemsList.addAll(listpost.getItems());
            adapter = new MainAdapter(itemsList) {
                @Override
                public void load() {
                    if(nextPageToken!=null){
                        getNextListPost();
                    }
                }
            };

            recyclerViewData.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerViewData.setHasFixedSize(true);
            staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
            staggeredGridLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(0);
            recyclerViewData.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);

}
```

My Adapter Code :

```
public abstract class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainViewHolder>{

    private List<BlogPostModel> responseBlogPost;

    public MainAdapter(List<BlogPostModel> responseBlogPost) {
        this.responseBlogPost = responseBlogPost;
    }

    public abstract void load();

    @Override
    public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_main,parent,false);
        return new MainViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MainViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final BlogPostModel model = responseBlogPost.get(position);
        ArrayList<String> urlImage = pullLinks(model.getContent());
        String firstImage = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < urlImage.size(); i++) {
            firstImage = urlImage.get(1);
            GlideCustomLoading.setImageFromURL(holder.itemView.getContext(), urlImage.get(0)
                    ,holder.avLoadingIndicatorView, holder.ivItemPost,holder.tvFailedLoadImage);
        }

        holder.tvTitleItemPost.setText(model.getTitle());
        final String finalFirstImage = firstImage;
        holder.llItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String id = String.valueOf(model.getId());
                DetailPostActivity.start(holder.itemView.getContext(), id, finalFirstImage, model.getTitle(), model.getUrl());
            }
        });


        if(position>=getItemCount()-1){
            load();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return responseBlogPost.size();
    }

    public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CardView cardViewItemPost;
        ImageView ivItemPost;
        TextView tvTitleItemPost;
        AVLoadingIndicatorView avLoadingIndicatorView;
        TextView tvFailedLoadImage;
        LinearLayout llItem;

        public MainViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cardViewItemPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_item_post);
            ivItemPost =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image_post);
            tvTitleItemPost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_post);
            avLoadingIndicatorView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avi_load);
            tvFailedLoadImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_gagal_menampilkan_gambar);
            llItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_item_post);

        }
    }

    private ArrayList pullLinks(String html) {
        ArrayList links = new ArrayList();
        Elements srcs = Jsoup.parse(html).select("[src]"); //get All tags containing "src"
        for (int i = 0; i < srcs.size(); i++) {
            links.add(srcs.get(i).attr("abs:src")); // get links of selected tags
        }
        return links;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code for MainAdapter. That's more likely to be the cause of the problem than your loading.

Comment: @IvanWooll : Main Adapter Code has updated, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with Jsoup I'm reasonably confident that it's the source of your scroll lag.

You are calling the method `pullLinks` in your `onBindViewHolder` method which is called every time a new view is added to your RecyclerView. I'm assuming pullLinks does some pretty intensive work that takes some time to complete.

What you would be better off doing is to add all of the data to each item in your `responseBlogPost` List before loading it in to the adapter.

Comment: That's right sir!! Thank you, Could you please suggest me how to extract image from html content?

Comment: I would open up a new question for that. Be specific about what you are doing, how you are doing it and your intentions, that will lead to good quality answers.